# Looping and filtering through a numpy array to cancel out subsequent related "events"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like the example below.

- The different columns represent different events.
- The 1s and 0s represent whether each event occurs. To be explicit, a 1 in column A means that event A occurs.
- The columns moving from left to right show progression through time, so A occurs first, then B, then C, etc.
- There are 20 columns and about 1M rows.

```
A  B  C  D  ...
1  1  1  1
1  1  1  0
1  1  0  0
1  0  0  0
...
```

The events are, however, related. Let's say that events A and C are related. If A does not occur, then C cannot. As such, what I am trying to do is, as I understand it:

- For each column:
- Select rows where A = 0 and C = 1
- Set the elements in C in this subset of rows to 0

To be clear, there are situations where there are more than one related event. For example, A, C, F and J could be related. Also, the columns in the numpy array are not named -- I included the A, B, C, &c headings for ease of explanation.

I have been doing this manually via:

```
df[(df[:,0] == 0) & (df[:,2] == 1), 2]
```

How can I store the events to make looping through the related events, and use this to update the numpy array?

Comment: You mean you want to identify rows that have a 1 but, somewhere to the left, have a 0?

Comment: Otherwise I don't see how this can be achieved without custom filters for each condition. I tried to boil it down to a more simplistic basis but now column B will get in the way if it has nothing to do with the relation of A and C